# How to write a test suite abstraction?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit

I have set of 10 generalized & parametrized tests that I would like to execute about 100 different reports.
Can I write some abstraction where all permutations are executed independently.

1. I find that its hard to debug if test variations are rolled up.
2. I also find its hard to read output of tests because my tests are executing lot of sql and I am printing it for test output. I would like to continue printing it.

```cs
 [Test]
 public void Test_one(Report reportVariation)
 {
  ....
 }
```

Comment: I am not certain what you are trying to do.  Do you have 100 basic things you want to test multiple functions with, or just 100 different tests to run?  I found the and junit report task useful to make it easy to read the results of lots of tests. I used it when I would have over 500 tests that were running.

Answer (score 1):

Test Case Source perhaps? http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5 or other possible useful attributes here @ http://www.pgs-soft.com/new-features-in-nunit-2-5-part-1-parameterized-tests.html